# Python: what's a function call on a mock object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have accidentally stumbled on this kind of notation:

```
>>> m = mock.Mock()
>>> m().my_value = 5
>>> 
>>> m
<Mock id='139823798337360'>
>>> m()
<Mock name='mock()' id='139823798364240'>
```

`m` is an object of type mock, `()` is a function call.  How can you function call an object?

I tried calling a normal object, and expectedly i got an exception

```
>>> class C(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> c()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'C' object is not callable
```

So this must be some kind of Mock magic.  What is it and  is it used for?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? There are currently at least two subquestions, and they are rather broad. Note that functions are objects, so technically ``()`` is an object call.

Comment: So apparently Mock defines `__call__()`, what is the intended use of this?

Comment: The same as for any other action on a Mock. To mock the action that could be done on the real object.

Comment: A function is just an object of type `function`, and is not the only kind of callable. You call non-function objects all the time. For example, `mock.Mock` is not a function, but a class. You generally instantiate a class by calling it.

Comment: function is an object, but an object is not a function.  Calling a class is a convention for actually calling a constructor which is a function.  This is the root of my confusion, calling a class (conventionally) creates an object, calling an object just executes a special function of that object if it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, any object is callable if it implements [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method.

Any function is callable as the function object implements `__call__`. Also, all classes are callable. so you can make an instance of the class

In your class, if you add `__call__` it'll look like this

```
class C(object):
    def __call__(self, *args):
        print("instance is called with %s", tuple(args))
```

`Mock` class defines `__call__` so you can track calls to mock object.

```
>>> m = Mock()
>>> m(3, 4)
<Mock name='mock()' id='140219558391696'>
>>> m.mock_calls
[call(3, 4)]
>>>
```

Comment: right, in this case Mock behaves as a function, which is fine.  What about
```
m(3,4).some_attribute = 7
```
First we want mock to behave as a function, but then use it as an object and manipulate it's attributes

Comment: That's also okay, This is to mock a behavior of an object. Think about `re.search().group`. `re.search()` returns a match object which has a property called `group`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this, as it seems my question wasn't too clear.
So notation:

```
m = mock.Mock()
m().my_value = 5
```

is used to mock factory functions.  When you need to mock a function that returns an object with certain properties.  Every call to `m()` returns mock object that is different from `m` itself, but the same one every time (usually every call to a factory function returns a new object).  So when a property of this object is set (like `m().my_value=5`), it will be available in any later calls to `m()`